# Which button was clicked that initiated the PreSaveAction function on SharePoint Task Edit form?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

This is my first question ever on stackoverflow so please bear with me if had any mistakes.

We are using SharePoint Online and want to have validation on Task Edit Form. The validation is for Approved and Rejected buttons separately. If a user clicks on Approved button it should validate people picker field for having a value however if he clicks on Rejected button then it should validate comments rich text editor box.

On the current Task Edit Form the buttons has the following onclick event:

```js
if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl34$g_c787a6e1_0aac_4259_aaa9_1ed77297a7ee$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", false, true))
```

The solution I have tried is to create and add a click event to the buttons and write my jquery (3.1.1). However then I am not able to post the form using the above mentioned code of WebForm_PostBackOptions. Hence I approached the SharePoint native validation PreSaveAction function which doesn't allow me to have separate validations for the fields.

Hence how can I capture which button was clicked and get its value in PreSaveAction function in order to run the validation?

Thank you and
Regards
Tanzim

Answer (score 1):

Alhamdulillaah, problem solved.

Following is the snippet in case someone else face similar issue:

```js
<script language="javascript">
$(function()
  {
    var butApproved = $("input[value='Approved']");
    var butRejected = $("input[value='Rejected']");
    var butSaveName = $("input[value='Save']").attr("name");
    var optionResult = "";
        
    butApproved.attr("onclick", "");
    butRejected.attr("onclick", "");
    
    butApproved.attr("onclick", "optionResult='Approved'; if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('" + butSaveName + "', '', true, '', '', false, true))");
    butRejected.attr("onclick", "optionResult='Rejected'; if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('" + butSaveName + "', '', true, '', '', false, true))");

  });

  function PreSaveAction()
  {
    if (optionResult == "Approved")
    {
      alert("Approved clicked");
      return false;
    }
    else if (optionResult == "Rejected")
    {
      alert("Rejected clicked");
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Something else happend");
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Tanzim